problem running mailhog under ubunjtu 24.04
Have been using mailhog with ubuntu server 22.04 to test mail send mail functionality. Mailhog does not output messages with ubuntu server version 24.04.

You've stated that you have a problem, but you have not given one iota of information that would help anyone look into your problem. All anyone can do is say "I am sorry you are having a problem."

Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].
